# VB - Reference a resource in a command prompt command

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, command-prompt

When using the eventvwr command line command you can pass an exported XML file to it using /v:"path to file"

I'm trying to do this using visual studio.

Right now I'm trying

```
Process.Start("CMD", "/C eventvwr " + Servername + " /v:" +
```

And that's where I get stuck.  I need it to pull in the xml file as a file and not the contents.  I currently have the xml file pulled in as a resource under project->properties->files.

Any help would be appreciated if this is at all possible.

Thank you.

Comment: You have to save it as a temporary file, then refer to the temp path in your CMD arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Dim xmlText as String = Properties.File
Dim path as String = "c:\temp\file.xml"; //or Path.GetTempPath() + "file.xml"
File.WriteAllText(path, xmlText)
```

Then:

```
Process.Start("CMD", "/C eventvwr " + Servername + " /v:" + path)
```

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly what this basically does is temporarily writes the contents of the XML document to an actual file?  Then I can just delete it after?  That sounds like it would work perfectly.  I'll try it, thank you!